# How to obtain all sites within a URL?

Tags: site-collection, site

Let's say i have this url:

http://mysharepoint.onprem.local/path1/path2/path3/path4

I need to be able to obtain all the sub-sites within the URL.

For example:

http://mysharepoint.onprem.local/path1/path2/path3/path4
is a site

http://mysharepoint.onprem.local/path1/path2/path3
is a site

http://mysharepoint.onprem.local/path1/path2
is not a site, just a context path.

http://mysharepoint.onprem.local/path1
is a site collection

Do I need to be able to back track through the url obtaining all the sub-sites? If so, given a URL, how can I determine if the URL is a sharepoint site or not?

Otherwise, what is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create script where you are spliting url by "/" and trying to `Get-SPSite` or `Get-SPWeb` for each elements (gradually stocked) in **Try/Catch statement** if it's true you can work with it, if its false it will end in Catch.

Comment: You're welcome :)